# How to run a linux executable from C++ stored in other folder

Tags: c++, linux, automation

The terminal commands to be run are :

```
cd folder1/folder2
sudo ./runnable
```

I am thinking of a solution such as :

```
exceute.run("cd folder1/folder2","sudo ./runnable")
```

in my C++ code. Moreover this should be done as SUPERUSER. Please help !!

Comment: You need to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), know about [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and understand what is [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). Your question is too broad. And be careful about security issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just call your program using an explicit path?

For example, if your program is located in /projects/folder1/folder2,
then you would have:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout<<"Starting runnable executable..."<<std::endl;
   std::system("cd /home/youbot/applications; sudo ./runnable"); 
   return 0;
}


chmod 775 /projects/folder1/folder2/runnable
```

Running your program as root is not recommended though.

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-run-as-root) link for more info on why it's not advisable to run a program using sudo.

Comment: Is execute.run() really used to run the commands ?
I just suggested that I need command like this

Comment: Can't cd to other folder

Comment: my executable is in another folder , how to change the directory from CURRENT folder to the folder of executable

Comment: system("cd /path/to/folder1/folder2");

Comment: I am running the c++ program from :
~/applications/winjoypad$
and want to get to :
~/applications$
I have tried :
system("cd /applications");
and also :
system("cd /");
and also :
system("cd ..");
BUT NOTHING Works :(

Comment: Instead of using '~', put the full path.  Try this:  std::system("cd /full/path/to/applications; sudo ./winjoypad");

Comment: To get the full path to ~, go to a terminal, and ececute "cd ~; pwd".

Comment: Thanks for support ! :)

Comment: I believe the answer might not be satisfactory, in particular beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) if the actual string passed to `system` is dynamically built from user input